# How do I solve my GitHub authentication. I was trying to push a code to my GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

How do I solve my GitHub authentication? I was trying to push a code to my GitHub repository and I got this error message

```
em@Abiodun-ADEDAPO-abeyjoe:~/Desktop/Upload to github/abeyjoe$ git push -u origin main
Username for 'https://github.com': abeyjoe
Password for 'https://abeyjoe@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/abeyjoe/abeyjoe.git/'
oem@Abiodun-ADEDAPO-abeyjoe:~/Desktop/Upload to github/abeyjoe$
```

I commited my code and pushed to a github repo "abeyjoe" with this command `git push -u origin main` but
it showed an authentication error.

Comment: Check how to conenct with SSH https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: It literally sends you the link to the docs on how to fix this: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls